# How do I select a specific class under a specific id?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/d4NxZ/1/

Here is my code. I want to change the context in right frame when i click the buttons. But these line of codes don't seem like working. I think it is because of selectors, I tried different selectors but it was no use.

```
$('#web-dash').click(function(){
    $(".graphs-dash>div:visible").slideUp('1000', function() {
        $("#whole .websitestats").slideDown('1000');
        $('#pie').hide();
        $('#toShow').val("1");
    });
})

$('#skill-dash').click(function(){
    $(".graphs-dash>div:visible").slideUp('1000', function() {
        $("#whole .skill").slideDown('1000');
        $('#pie').hide();
        $('#toShow').val("1");
    });
})
```

How can I select `#whole .skill` and `#whole .websitestats`? I made google searchs about selectors but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: FYI, you can attach the external files under External Resources.

Comment: @jycr753 If I understood your question correct, yes.

Comment: @yeyene Thank you, will use it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know whether I understood your issue correctly.

```
$("#whole .websitestats").slideDown('1000');
```

Even after executing above code `.websitestats` is not visible. Is this is you problem ?

`$("#whole .websitestats")` and `$("#whole .skill")` matches the respective elements correctly. But, display:none property is added in #whole div. As parent div is not visible child element also not visible.

Try

```
$("#whole").show().find(".skill").slideDown('1000');
```

Comment: I got it. But this time, it shows the whole `#whole` div. I think I need to change the logic of my code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#web-dash').click(function(){
    $(".graphs-dash>div:visible").slideUp('1000', function() {
        $("#whole").find(".websitestats").slideDown('1000');// use find function here
        $('#pie').hide();
        $('#toShow').val("1");
    });
});
$('#skill-dash').click(function(){
    $(".graphs-dash>div:visible").slideUp('1000', function() {
        $("#whole").find(".skill").slideDown('1000');// use find function here
        $('#pie').hide();
        $('#toShow').val("1");
    });
})
```

Find Docs http://api.jquery.com/find